# sed/grep - display 1st and 5th column, remove comma in 5th column and swap Last-First, and sort in alphabetical order by last name in /etc/passwd

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I need some sed/grep help with my `/etc/passwd` file. An example of an output in my /etc/passwd file is:

```
username1:x:5687:3794:Smith, Mike:/home/username1:/bin/bash
```

My first column are usernames and fifth column are Last Name, First and it isn't in alphabetical order in any way. I need to display the first column then display the fifth column in First Name Last Name sorted in alphabetical order by last name.

I have the sed command to display the fifth column in First Name Last Name sorted in alphabetical order by last name:

```
grep "$userid" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5 | sort | sed 's/^\(.*\), \(.*\)$/\2 \1/'
```

but simply adding `f1,5` in my cut command doesn't make the expected output, it removes the alphabetical order and just places the first column after their first name which is not what I am looking for.

I can only use the sed command. What I have and need help with is

```
grep "$userid" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,5 | sort | sed
```

I'm stuck here since I don't know much about the sed command, userid is just a variable I am reading from user input inside of a script for the first column.

So an example output would be:

```
username7    Abe Adams
username2    Jack Adams
username4    Ben Fab
username5    Jon Heat
```

Comment: You need to use the `sort` command to put them in alphabetical order, `sed` has no way to do that by itself.

Comment: I missed copying the sort command onto this website, fixed that, my original command had sort. Still have the same issues though regarding sed.

Comment: Sort should be last in the pipeline, and you need to use the `-k` option to tell it which field to sort by.

Comment: wrt `sed/grep help` - here you go: don't use them for this :-). It's very much a job for awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a colon separating the two fields if you use `cut -d: -f1,5`, so you write your `sed` script to expect that:

```
grep "$userid" /etc/passwd |
cut -d: -f1,5 |
sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\([^,]*\),[[:space:]]*\(.*\)$/\1  \3 \2/' |
sort -k3,3 -k2,2
```

The negated character classes are a useful way of separating fields.  Note that if the password entry doesn't contain a comma (and none of the accounts in the password file on my machine does), then the data is passed through `sed` unmodified.  You could work around that if necessary (with more options and a second `s///` expression) but it isn't clear that it's necessary.

It also isn't clear why you need to sort unless the value in `$userid` is some sort of regex that matches multiple rows in the password file.

Comment: wrt `grep "$userid" /etc/passwd` - if `userid` is `bert` that will also find `roberta` and it'll match anywhere across the whole line rather than just the userid field. You should **really** be using awk instead of grep+cut+sed for this - the result will be clearer, simpler, and more robust.

Comment: @EdMorton — yes, but the question is specific about what should be used.

Comment: I saw the OP said "I can only use the sed command" but you're not only using the sed command and nether were they in their question so I'm assuming what they really mean is they can't use non-standard tools like perl, ruby, python, etc. but are fine with the standard UNIX tools like grep, cut, sed, sort, and awk.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to match multiple users with the "userid" you search for and that you want it to be a string rather than regexp comparison, here's how to do it robustly:

```
$ awk -F':' -v userid='username' 'index($1,userid){n=split($5,names,/[ ,]+/); print $1, names[n], names[1]}' file |
    sort -k3
username1 Mike Smith
```

I'm using the split() that way to ensure the command works even if you have more than 2 parts to your name (e.g. Billy Bob Thornton).

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's an awk and sort combination that might be helpful for you:

```
sort -t: -k5,5 /etc/passwd | awk -F'[: ,]*' '{print $1,$6,$5 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This took me most of the day, and it looks like I'm too late now. :(

Anyway, here's my solution:-

File+.txt:-

```
username1:x:5687:3794:Smith, Mike:/home/username1:/bin/bash
username2:x:5687:3794:Smith, Bill:/home/username1:/bin/bash
username3:x:5687:3794:Smith, Sam:/home/username1:/bin/bash
username4:x:5687:3794:Smith, Bob:/home/username1:/bin/bash
username5:x:5687:3794:Smith, Steve:/home/username1:/bin/bash
```

Script+.txt:-

```
#!/bin/sh -x

init() {
IFS=":"

cat > edpop+.txt << EOF
1d
wq
EOF

cat > edcommands+.txt << EOF
1p
W tmp2+.txt
q
EOF

next
}

end () {
sort -r tmp+.txt > report+.txt
rm -v ./edcommands+.txt
rm -v ./edpop+.txt
IFS=" "
exit 0
}

next() {
[[ -s file+.txt ]] && main
end
}

main() {
ed -s file+.txt < edcommands+.txt
read var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 < tmp2+.txt

lastname=$(echo "${var5}" | cut -d',' -f1)
firstname=$(echo "${var5}" | cut -d',' -f2)
echo -e "${var1}\t${firstname} ${lastname}" >> tmp+.txt
ed -s file+.txt < edpop+.txt
rm -v ./tmp2+.txt
next
}

init
```

a}  Each line is initially read in with ed.

b}  Read and IFS are used to cut up each line into variables, with the colon as delimiter.

c}  Cut is used to cut up the firstname/lastname fields.

d}  Echo sends the newly constructed lines into a temp file.

e}  A reverse sort is performed on the temp file, and the result is sent into report+.txt.

f}  Ed is used to delete the first line from the input file, thus reducing the count by one.

g}  The loop resets.  When all of the lines have been popped off the input file-based stack, we exit.